# How can I implement interprocess communication in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core

I'm starting a process with Process and ProcessStartInfo, I need to communication the two processes with each other. The started process must communicate its start, end, and its results.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = xyz;

                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                Process p = Process.Start(psi);
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways for processes to communicate, and none of those are specific to .NET. It mostly depends on what is the nature of that communication.

Comment: Do you control the code of the monitored programs? If not, you'll have to decide if you want a copy of the program's output in your 'report' or just the exit code

Answer (score 0):

I had to settle for socket programming. Socket programming enabled me to communicate my processes with each other.